# Excel VBA Run Time error the second times

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, office-automation

Can anyone say me why the second time I run the macro I receive a runtime error?

```
Dim wApp as Object
Dim wDoc as Object
Set wApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add(Template:="Test.dotm", Visible:=True)
```

On Microsoft support:
"Visual Basic has established a reference to Word due to a line of code that calls a Word object, method, or property without qualifying it with a Word object variable. Visual Basic does not release this reference until you end the program. This errant reference interferes with automation code when the code is run more than once."
I don't see any unqualified object or method or property in my code.

Comment: What is the exact error (number and description)? Why don't you share the rest of the relevant code so we can see how you save and close the file and quit the word application?

Comment: Why do you create a new Word `Application` instance every time you run the code?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev because most of times the word are closed

Comment: @VBasic2008 The error is: "Run-time error '2146959355 (80080005)' Automation Error"

Comment: Have you tried using the full path of the file, e.g. `"C:\Test\Test.dotm"`? On a side note, the *Visible* argument's default parameter value is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's likely that MS Word is already running. So here are a couple of routines from my library to check if MS Word is already running or not, and to make a connection to the process.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Function MSWordIsRunning() As Boolean
    '--- quick check to see if an instance of MS Word is running
    Dim msApp As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set msApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err > 0 Then
        '--- not running
        MSWordIsRunning = False
    Else
        '--- running
        MSWordIsRunning = True
    End If
End Function

Public Function AttachToMSWordApplication() As Word.Application
    '--- finds an existing and running instance of MS Word, or starts
    '    the application if one is not already running
    Dim msApp As Word.Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Set msApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err > 0 Then
        '--- we have to start one
        '    an exception will be raised if the application is not installed
        Set msApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    Set AttachToMSWordApplication = msApp
End Function
```

Comment: I change the 3th line with  Set wApp = AttachToMSWordApplication(), and it doesn't work, Now I receive the error 91  on line 4 "Object Variable or with block variable not set"

Comment: Check the returned value of `wDoc` like this `If wDoc Is Nothing Then ...` and report/display a message that it failed. If it is failing, then add `Debug.Print Err` to `AttachToMSWordApplication` and find out why.